Почему change срабатывает раньше чем click?
На странице есть поле ввода и кнопка. На поле ввода назначено событие change, а на кнопку событие click. Если написать что-то в поле ввода и кликнуть по кнопке, не теряя фокуса с поля то, первым срабатывает событие change, а не click. почему так?

Когда ты кликаешь по кнопке, то, очевидно, фокус уходит с инпута...Очень странно, что такая простейшая вещь может быть на столько не очевидной))

ну то есть гарантировано все синхронные действия в обработчике change выполнятся до click?

клик - это нажать на кнопку мыши и отпустить.... .событие change срабатывает при потере фокуса, то есть сразу после первого нажатия на кнопку мыши вне этого инпута.....
